# Прибавлять +1 в ячейку excel

Tags: python

Есть код который должен прибавлять +1 в ячейку если в txt файле есть mac-адрес:

```
sheetnameYNR = fileopen['Sheet']
findYNR = open('File.txt', 'r')
wordYNR = 'ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff'

for _ in range(3):
    time.sleep(5)
    if wordYNR in findYNR.read():
        sheetnameYNR['E5'].value += 1
```

MAC-адрес в файле есть всегда, и по идее он должен записать +3 в ячейку, но от записывает только один раз и все. Т.Е. изначально в ячейке значение 0, после выполнения кода должно быть 3, а вмесчто этого значение 1. Подскажите что я не так делаю?

Comment: еще странно если условие сделать как:
if wordYNR NOT in findYNR.read():
и убрать мак-адрес из списка, то код работает как надо, значение в ячейке становится 3, а если вернуть все обратно, то снова прибавляет только 1 вместо 3

Answer (score 2):

Потому что с помощью `.read()` можно прочитать текст из открытого файла **только один раз**. Дальше чтение упрётся в конец файла. Если хотите опять начать читать, то нужно либо переоткрывать файл заново (открывать/закрывать файл на каждой итерации цикла), либо перемещать указатель с помощью `.seek(0)` в начало файла перед чтением, либо, если предполагается, что файл не будет меняться, то сохранять перед циклом всё прочтённое через `.read` в какую-то переменную, а в цикле уже проверять вхождение строки в эту переменную.

Что касается комментария - ничего удивительного, на последующих итерациях цикла вы читаете из файла пустой текст, естественно, в пустом тексте ничего не находится, обратное условие выполняется.